# Waterline Many-To-Many update with existing records

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to write an update of my model to allow my application to pass an array of Id's (or an array of object Id's) to the server and for the update function to remove all existing relations and add in the new ones.

For example the data I am sending is:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "newIds":[3,4,5,6,7],
}
```

the current ids in the database are:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

So after my update I would like the ids to be:

```
[3,4,5,6,7]
```

The update function I currently have is:

```
var id = req.param('id'),
newIds = req.param('newIds');
User.findOne({id: id})
.exec(function(err, results){
  if(err) return res.serverError(err);
  var user = results;

  if (user){
    if (newIds && newIds.length > 0) {
      user.ids.add(newIds);
    }

    user.save(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return res.serverError(err);
      };
      result.success = true;
      return res.json(result);
    });
  }
});
```

However when I call the update I get an error complaining about the relationships already being there (It complains about id's 3,4 and 5 as they already exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your `add() + save()` with `update()`.

```
var id = req.param('id'),
newIds = req.param('newIds');
User.update({id: id}, {ids: newIds})
.then(function(updatedUser) {
    result.success = true; // assuming you've defined result somewhere earlier
    return res.json(result)
})
.catch(res.serverError)
```

See: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/update

> An array of primary key values passed to .update() for a collection association will set the association to contain only the records with those primary key values provided. That is- it unlinks all other records from the association.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I defined it earlier in the function just forgot to add it to my question. Ill test it out and see if it works.